# swapExactETHForTokens How to work ? i need some exmple code

Tags: solidity, uniswap

```
receive() external payable {}
    function swapEthForTokens(uint256 ethAmount) public payable returns (uint256) {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
        path[1] = address(this);

        uint[] memory tokenAmount_ ; 

        // make the swap
        tokenAmount_ = uniswapV2Router.swapExactETHForTokens{ value: ethAmount }(
            0,
            path,
            address(this), // The contract
            block.timestamp
        );
        uint256 outputTokenCount = uint256(tokenAmount_[tokenAmount_.length - 1]);
        return outputTokenCount;
    }
```

exmple

if inside my contract have remain ETH
I would like my contract to use all remaining ETH  to token

after i add liquidity and swap token no problem but when i deposit eth to my contract and swap i got error
" The transaction cannot succeed due to error: undefined. This is probably an issue with one of the tokens you are swapping. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried change ***to*** input  address(this) to owner() and it work !!

```
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
        path[1] = address(this);

        uniswapV2Router.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{value: amount}(
            0, 
            path, 
            owner(), // <<<<<<<<< old bug it was address(this)
            block.timestamp
        );
        
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The general method I use for my contracts is as such:

```
function swapETHForTokens(uint256 amount) private {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
        path[1] = address(this);

        uniswapV2Router.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{value: amount}(0, path, deadAddress, block.timestamp.add(300));
        
        emit SwapETHForTokens(amount, path);
}
```

This function simply swaps amount of inputted WETH in the contract for tokens (assuming an ERC20 contract). If we wanted to swap everything I suggest writing a separate function:

```
function swapAllEthForTokens() external {
        swapETHForTokens(address(this).balance);
}
```

Also, it is generally good practice to keep functions like this private.

Answer (score 0):

Ive come across the same issue, i notice that external wallets work but not address(this), it causes the swapExactETHForTokens function to break.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/70552)